# How can I modify my subplot positions to stop them overwriting each other?

Tags: matlab, handle, subplot, axes

I am trying to create a subplot (6 plots) of world maps into which I am writing chosen shapefiles. My issue is with my placement of subplots: They are overwriting each other. I understand from the other questions like this on stackoverflow, that it is because the axes are overlapping somehow. But I thought I had created positions that they would just be 'side-by-side' (see code below). I have tried to make the axes transparent and that doesn't seem to help. My question is: how can I modify the plot positions so they won't overwrite each other?

The code I'm using (with the shapefile stuff removed) is:

```
clc;
clear all;
%First create the positions for the subplots
handle1=subplot(3,2,1);
H1=get(handle1,'position');
h1pos=H1+[-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1]; subplot(2,2,1,'Position',h1pos)
hold all

handle2=subplot(3,2,2);
H2=get(handle2,'position');
h2pos=H2+[-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1]; subplot(2,2,1,'Position',h2pos)

handle3=subplot(3,2,3);
H3=get(handle3,'position');
h3pos=H3+[-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1]; subplot(2,2,1,'Position',h3pos)

handle4=subplot(3,2,4);
H4=get(handle4,'position');
h4pos=H4+[-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1]; subplot(2,2,1,'Position',h4pos)

handle5=subplot(3,2,5);
H5=get(handle5,'position');
h5pos=H5+[-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1]; subplot(2,2,1,'Position',h5pos)

handle6=subplot(3,2,6);
H6=get(handle6,'position');
h6pos=H6+[-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1]; subplot(2,2,1,'Position',h6pos)

subplot(3,2,1,'Position',h1pos)
text(0.02,0.98,'(a)','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top');
%handle1=subplot(2,2,1);
%H1=get(handle1,'position');
%h1pos=H1+[-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1]; subplot(2,2,1,'Position',h1pos)
h=worldmap('world')
%     borders('countries', 'Color', 'black')

subplot(3,2,2,'Position',h2pos)
text(0.02,0.98,'(b)','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
h=worldmap('world')
%     borders('countries', 'Color', 'black') 

subplot(3,2,3,'Position',h3pos)
text(0.02,0.98,'(c)','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
h=worldmap('world')
%     borders('countries', 'Color', 'black') 

subplot(3,2,4,'Position',h4pos)
text(0.02,0.98,'(d)','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
h=worldmap('world')
%     borders('countries', 'Color', 'black') 

subplot(3,2,5,'Position',h5pos)
text(0.02,0.98,'(e)','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
h=worldmap('world')

subplot(3,2,6,'Position',h6pos)
text(0.02,0.98,'(f)','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
h=worldmap('world')
%     borders('countries', 'Color', 'black') 
%     borders('countries', 'Color', 'black')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB's `position` vector is defined as `[left bottom width height]`, and in your case, if you look at h1pos and h3pos, they are

```
h1pos = [0.0300    0.6093    0.4347    0.3157]
h3pos = [0.0300    0.3096    0.4347    0.3157]
```

`h1pos(2) - h3pos(2) = 0.2996 < 0.3157`, i.e. the distance between the axes is smaller than the height of your h1, and as a result there is a overlap, which leads to "subplot" deleting your axes.

To solve this, you can calculate your positions more carefully and either leave more space or reduce the height (by reducing the height to 0.05 would work). You can modify the position property just by doing something like `handle6.Position = [0.0300    0.3096    0.4347    0.3157];`

P.S. you could consider improve your coding style by reducing some redundancy. Here is a code snippet that would do the job

```
offset = [-0.05,-0.05,0.1,0.05];
pos = zeros(6, 4);

for ii = 1:6
    h = subplot(3,2,ii);
    pos(ii, :) = h.Position;
end

for ii = 1:6
    subplot('Position',pos(ii,:) + offset);
    text(0.02,0.98,['(' char('a'+ii-1) ')'],'Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top');
    h=worldmap('world');
end
```

Comment: @Zhe thanks! I needed to look at the width and height more closely as you pointed out. The **pos(ii,:) = h.position** syntax didn't work for me (Version 2013b) but **pos(ii, :) = get(h,'position')** did the job nicely.

Answer (score 1):

`subplot` by itself will create axes that don't overlap, but will delete any existing axes that do overlap. So put the six `subplot` calls first, and change their positions at the end. Use `set(handle1,'Position',h1pos)`, not `subplot(...)` to change the position. You can also use `axes` to create an axes object without deleting any existing overlapping axes. Since you're setting the position manually anyway, the `subplot` command has no advantage for you.

You could also consider using the new [`tiledlayout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html) functionality.

Comment: thanks @Cris Luengo. I don't have the "tiledlayout" functionality in my version but the advice to change the position afterwards is helpful.