# Cannot place an image just above a bar plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to print an image above a bar plot in the same figure, manually changing their position using the set command with the OuterPosition option.

This works only if the vertical coordinate of the image is at least 0.42, in fact if it is below this value then the image disappears.

How can I place the image below 0.42?

```
subplot(2,1,1)
imshow( imread('https://i.imgur.com/TVlQhpj.jpg') )
set(gca, 'OuterPosition', [.3 .42 .4 .4]);
subplot(2,1,2)
bar(1:10)
set(gca, 'OuterPosition', [.3 0 .35 .23]);
```

[image]

Comment: Presumably it starts overlapping with the second subplot there. Try to limit the size of that one, or try e.g. [`tiledlayout()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html) to reduce white space around subplots

Comment: @Adriaan when using `tiledlayout` I'm not able to change position and size of image and bar, do you know if it is possible?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60382966/7328782

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your MATLAB version is recent (>= R2019b), you could use [`tiledlayout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html) instead of subplot:

```
tiledlayout(2,1)

nexttile
imshow( imread('https://i.imgur.com/TVlQhpj.jpg') )

nexttile
bar(1:10)
```

which will place the map above the chart.

---

If you wish for the map to be *directly* above the chart, you will have to modify the dimensions manually as follows:

```
pos1 = [0.2 0.1 0.6 0.3];
subplot('Position',pos1)
bar(1:10)
pos2 = [0.2 0.41 0.6 0.3];
subplot('Position',pos2)
imshow( imread('https://i.imgur.com/TVlQhpj.jpg') )
```

[image]

Comment: It prints this "Warning: Unable to set 'Position', 'InnerPosition', 'OuterPosition', or 'ActivePositionProperty' for objects in a TiledChartLayout "

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to use your code. Just copy and paste mine in the command window...

Comment: @soundwave Replace your entire code with mine

Comment: I need to manually change the position and size of both image and bar plot

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Yes, but with your method I'm not able to change position and size of image and bar

Comment: @soundwave I've updated my answer with the `subplot` solution, which I believe does what you want

Answer (score 1):

The code you display does not match the animated image you link so we cannot know what is wrong in the code you *actually* used.

Setting the position of an `axes` is normally as straightforward as you were doing it. Worst case is the `axes` can move outside of visible area or be hidden behind other object. Consider the following example, the image never magically disapear, it just move where I tell it to:

```
function demo_move_image

% The code as provided -----------------------------------------------
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1) ;
imshow( imread('https://i.imgur.com/TVlQhpj.jpg') )
set(ax1, 'OuterPosition', [.3 .42 .4 .4]);
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2) ;
bar(1:10)
set(ax2, 'OuterPosition', [.3 0 .35 .23]);
% END - The code as provided -----------------------------------------

% Make a slider to control the vertical position of the image
uisld = uicontrol('Style','slider','Min',0,'Max',1,'Value',.42,...
    'Unit','norm','Position',[.95 0 .05 1],'Callback',@slidercb) ;
title(ax1,num2str(get(uisld,'Value')))

% Callback for the slider
    function slidercb(~,~)
        set(ax1, 'OuterPosition', [.3 get(uisld,'Value') .4 .4])
        title(ax1,num2str(get(uisld,'Value')))
    end
end
```

[image: moving image]

Comment: I made my animated image not with matlab but from 3 images, and uploading them on an online tool to make the gif. I don't know why you suspect that my code don't match the image, here you can see that the world map doesn't show when putting vertical index < 0.42 https://i.imgur.com/MKOKNqj.mp4 Your code also has this problem. I need a static figure where I can place the image freely above the bar plot

Comment: Which problem in my code? The image does not disapear! Try using `clf` statement in the console before rerunning the code the second time.

Comment: Nice answer, you went the extra mile here

Comment: @Hoki I need a static figure, not a scrollable thing, see my answer below with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Due to some reason, the `subplot()` command deletes the axes behind it, so it is better to use `axes()`.

```
ax1 = axes('OuterPosition', [.3 .35 .4 .4]);
imshow( imread('https://i.imgur.com/TVlQhpj.jpg') )
ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [.3 0 .35 .23]);
bar(1:10)
```